# How can Rebol READ asynchronous pluggable protol it herself implements

Tags: javascript, rebol

This article shows how to implement asynchronous pluggable protocol in rebol that can be read by firefox or ie or command line http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/17120/0/page/1

So for example if I define the reb:// protocol I could type it in browser and It will execute the handler in rebol.

But how can rebol itself interpret this same reb:// when doing a read:

```
read reb://blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to build a protocol handler and embed it within the rebol system as a scheme which converts reb:// to something that can interact with a port object.

there are a few rebol scheme tutorials on the net.

you can look at the scheme handlers directly if you want in order to modify them.  this has often been required in the past to fix aging protocols like ftp. (sometimes specifically for a single server software).

for example

probe system/schemes/whois

this is probably the oldest but the best article on the subject. this is strictly R2.  http://www.rebolforces.com/articles/protocols/

Comment: Sure there are a few but I'm not a "real" programmer without tutorial I'll have some difficult to dive into the code and understand it especially when it's gurus code who like to make syntax "elegant" but quite obscure for non initiates :)

Comment: I just added a link to a venerable article about port handlers.  its almost 10 years old, but still very useful today.